# Spring Boot - Why I cannot produce a String in RestController?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

In Spring Boot, I am configuring the server and everything is working, except of my RestController. I dont know why:

[image: 1]

(SO doesnt allow to include pictures yet, so here is a link)

Thats the little Controller class. Notice, that the method name in my Intellij IDEA
is **grey** - it is not used.

```
package com.example.intermediate.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class GrakaController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/graka", produces = "text/plain")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getSimpleString() {
        return "IT WORKED!";
    }
}
```

In Postman I try to get the String by using `http://localhost:8080/graka`: I am getting a 200 return code, but with empty response body, no matter which response body format I choose in Postman. But I should get "IT WORKED!" back I think.

I have been struggling for some hours with that. Who got any ideas? Thanks for every tip!

Comment: Maybe you didn't recompile your code? I tried to create spring boot app on https://start.spring.io/ with only web dependency and copy pasted your method inside controller and after that executed in console curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/graka" and I got proper response.

Comment: Try just open the URL in browser

Comment: Could you push the codebase somewhere, eg.GitHub for a while to see?

Comment: It works nice on Spring Boot 2.3.0, so what's the version of Spring boot you are using?

Comment: It works fine for Spring Boot 2.3.4. You have the controller in a different package than the main application. It may not be getting picked up by Spring to create a bean (but since you are getting a response of 200, that confuses me). Could you share your main application class?

Comment: I deleted the project but in my next project I had that mistake with the package, so probably you are right @devang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    @GetMapping("/graka") 
    public String getSimpleString(){ 
    return "IT WORKED!"; 
     }
```

Comment: I tried it, its not working. Just showing an empty response

Answer (score -1):

With Spring 4, if your Controller is annotated with @RestController,  you don't need the @ResponseBody annotation.

Use ResponseEntity.

```
@GetMapping("/graka")
public ResponseEntity<String> getSimpleString() {
    LOG.info("REST request get string value");
    return new ResponseEntity<>("{\"status\" : \"IT WORKED!\"}", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: The ResponseEntity just complicate the code. That is unnecessary in that case.

Comment: The ResponseBody shouldn't break the Controller. But that is right, it is optional with RestController.

Comment: Yes right, there are other options that satisfy our needs and they result in much cleaner code.  Using ResponseEntity seems to be state of the art to me

Comment: You don't need `ResponseEntity`. That is only needed if you need control over the response code, content and want to do more complex stuff.